# How can I style an element which shares the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a page which shares the same class, I want one page (top.cfm) to have a border with a background-color but I don't want the (landing page.cfm) to have the border or background-color. This is my code on jQuery. Where am I going wrong?

```
$(function(){
        if (window.location.pathname == "common/top.cfm") {
              $('.content-padding').show('.content-padding').css('background-color', '#fff', 'border', '1px solid #CCCCCC');
        } else (window.location.pathname == "common/landing_page.cfm")
        {
              $('.content-padding').css('background-color', '#E1E1E0', 'border', 'none')
        }
   });
```

Comment: Create an additional class just for the border and apply that second class to top only?

Comment: This is how my html is written, <div class="container main-content content-padding content-bordered container_12 clearfix">
   <div class="grid_12 clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>  if i add another class, it will still affect the top page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an `else` but with a conditional. try to use an `else if` instead.

And you can make two separate classes and use a `toggle class` on them, if you want.

**Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.pathname == "common/top.cfm") {    
       $('#content').toggleClass('content-padding-top');
  }else if(window.location.pathname == "common/landing_page.cfm"){
       $('#content').toggleClass('content-padding-landing-page');
  }
});
```

```css
.content-padding-top{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.content-padding-landing-page{
    background-color:#E1E1E0;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container main-content content-padding content-bordered container_12 clearfix" id="content">
  <div class="grid_12 clearfix">
 <div class="clearfix" >
          <h1>Page Content</h1>
        </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: you're missing the classes on html but i added those classes and nothing works

Comment: you don't need the classes in html, because you're using the `id="content"` to get the div and add the classes. Make sure `window.location.pathname` on the condicionals is correct, because if you change the conditionals to true, you will see it work. You can use `console.log (window.location.pathname)` to verify this.

Comment: I made an example with `false` and `true` in the conditionals. Link: https://codepen.io/guguedes00/pen/KKpQOZO. If you change `if (false)` to `if (true)` you will see it change.

Comment: It worked!! my file paths were all wrong, took me hours, you're a life saver! thank you and god bless you man!!!